# Click child component by clicking the parent component

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to pass the click event from the parent to the child? So when `Button` is clicked `FileUpload` is clicked too. My working code is here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/uploadbutton-78h2d

```
<Button>
 <Dialog>
      <FileUpload/>
 </Dialog>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply have the `onClick` event listener on the Button instead of the FileUpload (or have it on both but make sure you're stopping propagation so it doesn't double-fire the event.

Comment: Can you please look at my codesandbox? `UploadButton.js`

Comment: So you're wanting it to automatically open the file explorer when a user clicks on the "Upload 3D Model" button?

Comment: If that's the case, then I don't see a way of passing the click event off to the custom package you're using for your dropzone. However, their docs do seem to indicate an ability to manipulate the "input" field which seems to be the file explorer window. However, I couldn't get it to work in codesandbox. It may be worth reaching out to the maintainers of the package you're using to see if this scenario is possible or if you can submit an issue to their github for it to be added in the future.

Comment: Okay, I will do that. Thank you!